# remove extra lines in crystal report in detail section

Tags: c#, .net, windows, crystal-reports

i have windows application in which i am using crystal report.
i use to have two sub-report in one crystal report.In my report,i am loading two sub reports
In `Report-Header` section i am loading first sub-report and second in `Report-Footer` section.In my Detail section i am loading actual data.When number of records in detail section are more my `Report-Footer` goes to next page but problem is that my data in details section shows extra lines and spaces which i have used for formatting.i want to limit lines when records end on details section.
**i am uploading img of report for reference purpose. i have marked extra space with red box.**.!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the report footer is set to Keep Together, OR if the SUB REPORT is set to Keep Together, this can force the footer/sub report to start on the next page.  Check and uncheck : check the "Keep Together" setting in Section Expert and uncheck if set, and check "Keep Object Together" in Format SubReport and uncheck if set.  I betting it's the sub report object, tho.